# Tag photos outside Facebook using FBConnect and Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, facebook

I have downloaded a **Wordpress** plugin that enables **facebook Connect** in my site, allowing users to "comment out" and "like" the posts and photos.

As most of users are already logged in facebook when they reach our site, is it possible to let them **tag their friends in the photos**, and save that information so people can later see the names?

I've seen some some javascript code that let you save and load tags in specific coordinates, but i don't know where to begin. Is there a plugin that enables this, any ideas?

Sincerely